# Excel function error you've entered too many arguments for this function

Tags: excel

I've got two beginning options:

If cell J3 is "B" then this formula applies to cell `M3`:

`=IF(M3="t",I3-F3,IF(M3="s1",G3-F3,H3-F3))`

and if the cell J3 is "S" then the formula changes a bit to:

`=IF(M3="t",F3-I3,IF(M3="s1",F3-G3,F3-H3))`

I combined these formulas to

`=IF(J3="b",M3="t",I3-F3,IF(M3="s1",G3-F3,H3-F3),IF(M3="t",F3-I3,IF(M3="s1",F3-G3,F3-H3)))`

and thus I'm getting the error you've entered too many arguments for this function.....

Any help reconciling this error?

Comment: Hi, try this link https://www.exceldome.com/solutions/if-and-or-functions-combined/

Comment: You should check the first part of the formula 'IF(J3="b",M3="t",....'  the 2nd argument 'M3="t", is strange!

Answer (score 1):

The formula =(1-(J3="s")*2)*IF(M3="t",I3-F3,IF(M3="s1",G3-F3,H3-F3)) does the job... Thanks